# Is it possible hide/show choice items related another field?

Tags: sharepoint

is it possible to hide/show column items based on another field in SharePoint 365?

Example:

In first column I have:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

In second column I have:

- Item A
- Item B
- Item C
- Item D

I need when I select the item in first column, in the second only appaers some of them:

| First Column | Second Colum |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1 | Item A |
| Item 1 | Item B |
| Item 2 | Item C |
| Item 3 | Item D |

PS: I don't have "admin center" access and I can't use Power Apps in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article to create two lists (First list and Second list) to store the item values of the two columns, and then reference them in the main list through the lookup column. Add a Content Editor Web Part to implement changes using HTML (require editing the page in classic mode).

Script details: [column choice based on the value of another column choice](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175108/column-choice-based-on-the-value-of-another-column-choice)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience, you cannot do this using SharePoint default capabilities.

You have below options:

1. Easiest way: Use Power Apps to customize list forms and cascading dropdowns. I know you mentioned you can't use Power Apps - but this is easiest way (check other options below)

   a. [Working with Cascading Lists in SharePoint and Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/working-with-cascading-lists-in-sharepoint-and-powerapps) 
   b. [Create dependent drop-down lists in a canvas app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/dependent-drop-down-lists)
2. Completely customize list form using SPFx form customizer: [Build your first Form customizer extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer) - lot of development work needed
3. Use JSON formatting - You can use list [JSON view formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-list-formatting) to add new items from within list view if you have less number of fields to submit while creating new items.

   Example: [Dependent-DropDown](https://github.com/Fedes365/Microsoft-Lists-Templates/tree/main/Dependent-DropDown)